# Get variable from ansible inventory from specific group

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get specific variables from specific group, but it seems to lead me to strange results .

Host file example:

```
[server_machine]
zeus     account=app1

[agent_machine]

machine1   account=agent port_a=1000  port_b=1001 
machine2   account=agent port_a=1200  port_b=1201 
machine3   account=agent port_a=1300  port_b=1301
```

What I'm trying to do is to run script on the `server_machine` group with parameters I get from the `agent_machines` group.

This way the script will run 3 times on `server_machine` with all ports combinations.

So basically I need playbook which might look like this:

```
- hosts: server_machine

- tasks:
    - command: test.py --port_1 {{item}}  --port_2 {{item}}
      with_items:{{group.agent_machine.port_a, group.agent_machine.port_b }}
```

However, I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- command: test.py --port_1 {{ hostvars[item]["port_a"] }} --port_2 {{ hostvars[item]["port_b"] }}
  with_items: groups["agent_machine"]
```

Comment: i still can't make it to work . 
I'm getting the following error :
TASK: [shell echo one port name is  {{ hostvars[item]["port_a"] }}] ******
fatal: [vl-jd-ctm01] => with_items expects a list or a set

Comment: Try to output `groups["agent_machine"]` with a debug task to see what is inside. In theory it should contain a list of hosts as defined in your inventory.

Comment: Brilliant . works .
my mistake was with the group name .
thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

That's a good use-case for ['delegate_to'](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html):

```
  - hosts: agent_machine
    tasks:
      - command: test.py --port_1 {{port_a}}  --port_2 {{port_b}}
        delegate_to: zeus
```